# error LNK2019 when trying to create a GamePad using DirectXTK

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm following the [DirectXTK GamePad tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/GamePad) on how to incorparate a GamePad into my application but I'm getting an *errorLNK2019* when trying to create the GamePad.

So far I've:

- included **GamePad.h** to my *Controller* header file
- Added

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<DirectX::GamePad> mGamePad;
  ```

  in my *Controller class*
- In Controller::Init() added

  ```
  mGamePad = std::make_unique<GamePad>();
  ```

And when I add that last line of code I get errors (loong ones):

```
DirectXTK.lib(GamePad.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RoGetActivationFactory referenced in function "long __cdecl ABI::Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory<struct ABI::Windows::Gaming::Input::IGamepadStatics>(struct HSTRING__ *,struct ABI::Windows::Gaming::Input::IGamepadStatics * *)" (??$GetActivationFactory@UIGamepadStatics@Input@Gaming@Windows@ABI@@@Foundation@Windows@ABI@@YAJPEAUHSTRING__@@PEAPEAUIGamepadStatics@Input@Gaming@12@@Z)
DirectXTK.lib(GamePad.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WindowsCreateStringReference referenced in function "private: void __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HStringReference::CreateReference(wchar_t const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateReference@HStringReference@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@AEAAXPEB_WII@Z)
fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

In my application I already use the [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch) without any problems so I'm guessing that I've done all the right things when I included [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) to my solution.

I've also tried to create the GamePad using

```
mGamePad.reset( new GamePad() );
```

that I found in an [older version](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Game%20controller%20input&referringTitle=GamePad) of the tutorial.

Also.. The controller is inserted..
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link your project with `RuntimeObject.lib`

Answer (score 1):

When DirectX Tool Kit's `GamePad` class is built for Windows 10 (i.e. `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00`) it uses the new `Windows.Gaming.Input` Windows Runtime classes instead of XINPUT.

If you are building for the Universal Windows Platform, then you already have Windows Runtime initialized, `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0a00` and are likely linking against `RuntimeObject.lib`.

If you are building a Windows desktop (aka Win32 or "classic" app), then first make sure you really intend to be making it for Windows 10 only. There are a [plethora of different vcxproj files](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK) for DirectX Tool Kit depending on exactly what platform you are targeting. If you do want to be targeting Windows 10 only with your Windows desktop app, that's totally cool but you'll need to explicitly initialize Windows Runtime for your app.

**TL;DR:** If you are making a Windows desktop app that requires Windows 10, then link with `RuntimeObject.lib` and add this to your app initialization (replacing `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`):

```
Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(initialize))
    return 1;
```

If you are not making a Windows desktop app that requires Windows 10, and you are not making a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, then use a different version of the DirectX Tool Kit that's built for Windows 7 compatibility.

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/09/05/directx-tool-kit-now-with-gamepads/)